# Activation rules on SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube, static-analysis

I try to do an integration between SonarQube and the Robotframework languge, so I create a plugin with java contain the class of creation Issue Related to a rule of tool nommed Rflint:

```
@Override
public void execute(SensorContext context) {
    FileSystem fs = context.fileSystem();
    Iterable<InputFile> inputFiles = fs.inputFiles(fs.predicates().hasLanguage("Robot"));
    for (InputFile inputFile : inputFiles) {
      // no need to define the severity as it is automatically set according
      // to the configured Quality profile
      NewIssue newIssue = context.newIssue()
        .forRule(RobotRulesDefinition.No_operation)

        // gap is used to estimate the remediation cost to fix the debt
        .gap(ARBITRARY_GAP);


      NewIssueLocation primaryLocation = newIssue.newLocation()
        .on(inputfile)
        .at(inputfile.selectLine(LINE_1))
        .message("You can't do anything. This is first line!");
      newIssue.at(primaryLocation);
      newIssue.save();
    }
  }
}
```

But the problem that when I scan my project Robot, SonarQube didn't use my rule in the analysis